# How do I disable a button when there is not text in the textview?

Tags: ios, swift, textview

Im trying to disable the save button when there is no text in the text view and enable when there is text in the text view. I have this code but nothing happens the button is enabled even though there is not text in the textview. Here is the code I have:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {


    if textView.text.characters.count > 0 {
        button.enabled = true
    }


    if textView.text.characters.count < 0 {
        button.enabled = false
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UITextViewDelegate method [`textViewDidChange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidChange:).

Something like:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)
{
    if textView.text.characters.count > 0 {
        button.enabled = true
    }


    if textView.text.characters.count < 0 {
        button.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: the save button stays enabled even though there is no text in the text view.

Comment: yes, I was going to tell you to make sure you set your delegate.  I am glad you are all set!

Comment: I put button.enabled = false in the viewDidLoad. Thanks!